# UIButton performance in UITableViewCell vs UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I'd like to add a UIButton to a custom UITableViewCell (programmatically). This is easy to do, but I'm finding that the "performance" of the button in the cell is slow - that is, when I touch the button, there is quite a bit of delay until the button visually goes into the highlighted state. The same type of button on a regular UIView is very responsive in comparison.

In order to isolate the problem, I've created two views - one is a simple UIView, the other is a UITableView with only one UITableViewCell. I've added buttons to both views (the UIView and the UITableViewCell), and the performance difference is quite striking.

I've searched the web and read the Apple docs but haven't really found the cause of the problem. My guess is that it somehow has to do with the responder chain, but I can't quite put my finger on it. I must be doing something wrong, and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Demo code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property UITableView* myTableView;
@property UIView* myView;
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myTableView, myView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self initMyView];
        [self initMyTableView];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) initMyView {
    UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,100)];
    self.myView = newView;
    // button on regularView
    UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedMyButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButton setTitle:@"I'm fast" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 160.0, 30.0)];
    [[self myView] addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void) initMyTableView {
    UITableView *newTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-100) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    self.myTableView = newTableView;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
}

-(void) pressedMyButton {
    NSLog(@"pressedMyButton");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self view] addSubview:self.myView];
    [[self view] addSubview:self.myTableView];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    if (customCell == nil) {
       customCell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }
    return customCell;
}

@end
```

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton* cellButton;
@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize cellButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // button within cell
        cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedCellButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cellButton setTitle:@"I'm sluggish" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cellButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 160.0, 30.0)];
        [self addSubview:cellButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) pressedCellButton {
    NSLog(@"pressedCellButton");
}

@end
```

Comment: This is sort of a guess but ill throw it out there: in your custom cell implementation have you tried using self.cellButton to make use of the property rather than accessing the ivar? Does that make any difference?

Comment: No difference when using property rather than ivar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with what you're doing (I tested it, and it is a little slow, but I wouldn't call it "sluggish"). It probably has to do with the various gesture recognizers attached to a table view -- the operating system has to figure out what gesture is happening, and that may cause a slight delay. This is the log of tableView.gestureRecognizers:

```
2012-10-09 20:34:12.355 SlowButtonsInTableView[3635:c07] (
    "<UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer: 0x71b42b0; state = Possible; delaysTouchesBegan = YES; view = <UITableView 0x789f800>; target= <(action=delayed:, target=<UITableView 0x789f800>)>>",
    "<UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer: 0x71b4940; state = Possible; delaysTouchesEnded = NO; view = <UITableView 0x789f800>; target= <(action=handlePan:, target=<UITableView 0x789f800>)>>",
    "<UISwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x71b4e00; state = Possible; view = <UITableView 0x789f800>; target= <(action=handleSwipe:, target=<UITableView 0x789f800>)>; direction = right,left>",
    "<UIGobblerGestureRecognizer: 0x71b5100; state = Possible; enabled = NO; view = <UITableView 0x789f800>>"
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know about tableView.gestureRecognizers, that's a great lead. Given that some of these are private (i.e. UIGobblerGestureRecognizer) there's probably not much one can do about it. I do agree with you that "sluggish" is perhaps too strong, but it's noticeable enough that it bothers me - will probably just stay away from highlighting the button in the first place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

On the table view, under section "scroll view" there is the option "delays content touches"... remove it and the delay on button is gone but in this way table scroll don't start dragging the button.

Comment: +1. This is real answer to the question. I was looking for `delays content touches` but i had `tableviewcell` selected instead of whole table in IB :D

Answer (score -1):

With scrolling on table view not enabled the delay disappear completely, probably the delay is caused by the gesture necessary for scrolling